# What is the internal pressure of a tethered hot air balloon?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

This question is for the review portion of a thermodynamics class:

> A small hot-air balloon has a volume of $15.0 m^3$ and is open at the
> bottom. The air inside the balloon is at an average temperature of
> $75^{\circ}C$, while the air next to the balloon has a temperature of
> $24^{\circ}C$, and a pressure, on average, of $1.00 atm$. The balloon
> is tethered to prevent it from rising, and the tension in the tether
> is $10 N$. Use $0.0290 \frac{kg}{mol}$ for the molar mass of air.
> Neglect the gravitational force on the fabric of the balloon. What is
> the pressure, on average, inside the balloon?

I've been trying to figure this question out off and on for a couple days, and I must be missing some key concept or relation. My first instinct was that the pressure inside would always match the outside since you are ignoring the effect of gravity on the fabric.

It seems that you would have to know the mass or amount of moles to find the pressure. However, all of that other information present, makes me think that is incorrect. I can't figure out a way that you could know the number of molecules or the mass without already knowing the pressure.

The key formulas I've been trying to use are below:
$$PV = nRT$$
$$v_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}} \approx 547\frac{m}{s}$$
$$P = \frac{F_z}{L^2} = \frac{1}{2}m(v_{rms})^{2} = \frac{nM(v_{rms})^{2}}{3V}$$

In every direction I run into the same road block. I don't know how to determine the amount or mass of the air in the balloon without knowing pressure. Additionally, the $L$ and $V$ in the last equation above seem to only be defined for a box which a balloon surely isn't.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to get into molecular speeds. Knowledge of the tether force is key: The mass of the hot air in that volume weighs 10 N less than the same volume of room-temperature air, correct?

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed. (I got ~1.1atm = P, hopefully that is right) I plan on posting the work through later in hopes it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you wrote in the comments that you found the answer before I wrote this answer, I will share my solution in order to provide alternative solutions for better understanding. Also, even though the physical principle between different answers given to this question is same, I think the solution I provide is the simplest and the one that you are probably  familiar at most.
The situation described in the question can be analysed in view of buoyancy force. In order to accomplish such an analysis, we have take into account the density of air both inside and outside the balloon.
\begin{equation}
P={\rho}R_{air}T\\
{\rho}=\frac{P}{R_{air}T}\\
\end{equation}
Density of the air outside of the balloon is:
\begin{equation}
{\rho_{out}}=\frac{1atm}{\frac{8.206*10^{-5}atm.m^3.mol^{-1}K^{-1}*297.15K}{0.029.kg.mol^{-1}}}=1.1893\frac{kg}{m^3}
\end{equation}
If we use simple free-body diagram, we would obtain a force balance as follows:
\begin{equation}
F_{buoyancy}=F_{weight}+F_{tether}\\
{\rho_{out}}gV=m_{in}g+10
\end{equation}
Notice that I did not neglect the gravitational force acting on the hot air but I only neglected that acting on the fabric of the balloon. Since $m_{in}=\rho_{in}V_{in}$, we can write the force balance as follows:
\begin{equation}
\rho_{out}gV=\rho_{in}gV+10\\
(\rho_{out}-\rho_{in})gV=10\\
\rho_{in}=\rho_{out}-\frac{10}{gV}\\
\rho_{in}=1.1893\frac{kg}{m^3}-\frac{10\frac{kg.m}{s^2}}{9.807\frac{m}{s^2}*15m^3}=1.1213\frac{kg}{m^3}
\end{equation}
Now, the only thing we have to do in order to evaluate the pressure inside the balloon is:
\begin{equation}
P_{in}=\rho_{in}R_{air}T_{in}=1.1213\frac{kg}{m^3}*\frac{8.206*10^{-5}\frac{atm.m^3}{mol.K}}{0.029\frac{kg}{mol}}*(273.15+75)K\\
P_{in}=1.1046\space atm
\end{equation}
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from chemomechanics "There's no need to get into molecular speeds. Knowledge of the tether force is key: The mass of the hot air in that volume weighs 10 N less than the same volume of room-temperature air, correct?" was what I needed to figure it out. If that isn't enough for people then below is the general form of the solution.

The answer to the question is given by the equation:

$$P_{b} = \frac{n_{b}RT_{b}}{V_{b}}$$

The limiting value for this answer is $n_{b}$. There exists some value that when added to the number of moles of air outside the balloon you get the number inside.

$$n_b = n_{air} + \Delta n$$

That $\Delta n$ is related to some $\Delta m$ (mass) via the molar mass:

$$ \Delta n = \frac{\Delta m}{M_{air}} $$

That difference of mass is given by the force acting on the tether using $F = ma$

$$\Delta m = \frac{F_{tether}}{g}$$
where $g$ is acceleration due to gravity. Finally we need the $n_{air}$ present in the same volume as the amount of air in the balloon.
$$n_{air} = \frac{P_{air}V_{b}}{RT_{air}}$$

Eventually you should end up with $P_b \approx 1.1\ atm$